# textfield that support html chars

Tags: php, html, textfield

I have been searching for a while after how i can set up a form with a textfield that supports and that can publish html characters.

I have a news form that is gonna publish news on the front page. 
There is a input for title, textfield for news and a input for published by.

I want to be able to write breaklines and paragraphs in this textfield so that it is published as html so breaklines and paragraphs are there instead of visible as `<br>` `<p>` etc.

How is this done without downloading rich textfield thingy and implement it?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say `textfield` do you mean `textarea`?

Comment: Yeah i mean textarea

Comment: Have you looked at `htmlentities` for encoding and `html_entity_decode` for decoding text? Store in the db in encoded format, display on the page in decoded format etc

Answer (score 0):

In general, for such requirement you should try WYSIWYG editors for example TinyMCE, CKEditor. You can pick one as per your requirement from [here](http://1stwebdesigner.com/best-wysiwyg-html-editor/).

Comment: I have been using CKEditor before, but i was hoping i could do this without that one.